# Timeout between client & server running on different Internet hosts

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

### Client Code

```
public class dayc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader d=null;
        Socket sk=null;
        String s="localhost";
        int port=5003;
        sk=new Socket(" remote machine ip ",port);
        d=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        while(true)
        {
            String sp=d.readLine();
            System.out.println(sp);

        }

    }

}
```

### Server Code

```
public class days {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port=5003;
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket sk=ss.accept();
        PrintWriter my=new PrintWriter(sk.getOutputStream());
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        Date d=c.getTime();
        my.println(d.toString());
        my.flush();
        ss.close();
    }

}
```

The client & server are running on different machines.

### Error

connection timeout

Comment: Be sure to include a clear "question" in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your server code is creating a socket, but the accept is supposed to be in a loop to keep listening and accepting connections., otherwise it will keep giving connection timeout.

See if that helps.